# std::map with different data types for values

Tags: c++, dictionary, stdmap

I have been searching the forums and google and having a hard time understanding how I can do what I want.

My example is based of typical dataset you see for an election. I want to split a delimited string and create a map to access later 
The string looks like this: 
"name=candidate1;vote=1000;percent=10.5"

I am able to create my map of strings as follows

```
    while (getline(oss, key, '=') && getline(oss, value))
    {

      mCanData.insert(std::pair<std::string, std::string>(key, value));

    }
```

What I would like to do, and I do not know if this is possible, is to insert the values in the map with different datatypes(i.e.key = "name" value ="candidate1", key = "vote" value =1000, key="percent" value=10.5).  The map I want to create will set a private class variable that can be accessed later through a getter by other classes.  I am not able to use the boost library so please do not suggest that.

Any help would be great as I am lost right now. If there is a better way to go about this I would like to know that as well.

Comment: How will you know what types each of the values should have? Are you going to remember that `vote` is always an `unsigned int`, or are you going to try to parse it and notice that it's entirely numeric and there's not decimal point?

Comment: There's a better way to do what you're trying, but it's not clear what you're really trying to achieve.  **Compile time** happens before **runtime**.  If a runtime string determines the type you're getting, the compiler isn't going to know what type it is.  It won't be able to generate the proper code.

Comment: I think you need to revisit how you're organizing your data.  Mixing like this caused me endless headaches. Plus I was doing it wrong :(

Comment: The different data types can all be decided at compile time. Name will always be a string, vote will always be an int, etc

Comment: Thank you all, this is very helpful

Answer (score 6):

If you really want to put not structured data in your map, in C++17 you can use `std::variant` to do that and thus *visit* it to get back your data.
It follows a minimal, working example:

```
#include <variant>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::map<std::string, std::variant<std::string, int, double>> mm;
    mm["name"] = "candidate1";
    mm["vote"] = 1000;
    mm["percent"] = 10.5;

    auto visitor = [](auto data){ std::cout << data << std::endl; };
    std::visit(visitor, mm["name"]);
    std::visit(visitor, mm["vote"]);
    std::visit(visitor, mm["percent"]);
}
```

See it up and running on [wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wTipWzC6AskQmY7g).
If it works for you mostly depends on the fact that you can use or not C++17. You didn't specify it, so it's hard to say.

---

That being said, structured data ([as suggested by @rici](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47404936/4987285)) looks like a far better solution to the problem.
However we cannot say neither what's the real problem nor how you designed the rest of the code, so it's worth it mentioning also `std::variant` probably.

Answer (score 4):

In a C++ `std::map`, all the values have the same type.

Generally, when you have structured data like that, you want to define a structured type:

```
class Vote {
  public:
    std::string name;
    int         vote;
    double      percent;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this with no C++ version dependency:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <cstdlib>


class Vote {
public:
    enum DATA_TYPE
    {
        STRING,
        INT,
        DOUBLE
    };
    Vote(int value)
        : m_type(DATA_TYPE::INT), m_ptr(new int(value)){}
    Vote(std::string& value)
        : m_type(DATA_TYPE::STRING), m_ptr(new std::string(value)){}
    Vote(double value)
        : m_type(DATA_TYPE::DOUBLE), m_ptr(new double(value)){}
    int toInt() {
        switch (m_type) {
        case DATA_TYPE::INT:
            return *(static_cast<int*>(m_ptr));
            break;
        case DATA_TYPE::DOUBLE:
            return (int)*(static_cast<double*>(m_ptr));
            break;
        case DATA_TYPE::STRING:
            return string2int(*(static_cast<std::string*>(m_ptr)));
        }
    }
    double toDouble() {
        switch (m_type) {
        case DATA_TYPE::INT:
            return (double)*(static_cast<int*>(m_ptr));
            break;
        case DATA_TYPE::DOUBLE:
            return *(static_cast<double*>(m_ptr));
            break;
        case DATA_TYPE::STRING:
            return string2double(*(static_cast<std::string*>(m_ptr)));
        }
    }
    std::string toString() {
        switch (m_type) {
        case DATA_TYPE::INT:
            return int2string(*(static_cast<int*>(m_ptr)));
            break;
        case DATA_TYPE::DOUBLE:
            return double2string(*(static_cast<double*>(m_ptr)));
            break;
        case DATA_TYPE::STRING:
            return *(static_cast<std::string*>(m_ptr));
        }
    }
    int string2int(std::string str)
    {
        return atoi(str.c_str());
    }
    double string2double(std::string str)
    {
        return atof(str.c_str());
    }
    std::string int2string(int value)
    {
        char buffer[10];
        itoa(value, buffer, 10);
        return std::string(buffer);
    }
    std::string double2string(double value)
    {
        char buffer[24];
        sprintf(buffer,"%f", value);
        return std::string(buffer);
    }
    DATA_TYPE type()
    {
        return m_type;
    }
private:
    std::string m_strValue;
    int m_intValue;
    double m_douValue;
    DATA_TYPE m_type;
    void *m_ptr;
};

int main()
{

    std::map<std::string, Vote> map;
    map.insert(std::pair<std::string, Vote>("Data1", 2));
    map.insert(std::pair<std::string, Vote>("Data2", 2.2));
    std::string Data3Value("1.31232");
    map.insert(std::pair<std::string, Vote>("Data3", Data3Value));

    for (std::map<std::string, Vote>::iterator it_map = map.begin();
         it_map != map.end();
         it_map ++) {
        Vote::DATA_TYPE type = (*it_map).second.type();
        switch (type) {
        case Vote::DATA_TYPE::INT:
            std::cout << "Key: " << (*it_map).first << ", value: " << (*it_map).second.toInt() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Key: " << (*it_map).first << ", value: " << (*it_map).second.toDouble() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Key: " << (*it_map).first << ", value: " << (*it_map).second.toString() << std::endl;
            break;
        case Vote::DATA_TYPE::DOUBLE:
            std::cout << "Key: " << (*it_map).first << ", value: " << (*it_map).second.toInt() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Key: " << (*it_map).first << ", value: " << (*it_map).second.toDouble() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Key: " << (*it_map).first << ", value: " << (*it_map).second.toString() << std::endl;
            break;
        case Vote::DATA_TYPE::STRING:
            std::cout << "Key: " << (*it_map).first << ", value: " << (*it_map).second.toInt() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Key: " << (*it_map).first << ", value: " << (*it_map).second.toDouble() << std::endl;
            std::cout << "Key: " << (*it_map).first << ", value: " << (*it_map).second.toString() << std::endl;
            break;
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

You can provide 3 type constructor and then you can accept 3 types to construct the objects, and then provide a void pointer, point to the data we "new" when constructing the object. When we call toInt(), toDouble(), toString() functions and use static_cast to cast pointer to the data type we want.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Rici above the correct approach should be to have a user defined type such as a class or struct and use it as key. In your case you can even just use set instead of map. Do remember to provide your comparator function or a < operator for your user defined type. So your design will look something like below.

```
struct Vote {
    std::string name;
    int         vote;
    double      percent;
};

struct myComparator
{
    bool operator() (const Vote& obj1, const Vote& obj2)
    {
      // Write your comparison logic which will be used by your container while inserting the data
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::set<Vote, myComparator> mySet;
    // Do your insertion and other operations.
    return 0;
}
```